# Python requests.post failed with SSL error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the following error when trying requests.post(url). I am using python 2.7.10. I have tried Custom Http Adapter solution provided in one of the thread but no luck..

```
       File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 531, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 518, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 661, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 214, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 639, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 512, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Comment: The server you are talking to is not speaking SSL/TLS (properly). It is fauty, the connection is compromised or you are trying to make an HTTPS connection to an HTTP service.

Comment: It is working if with python version : 2.7.5. Problem is with 2.7.10

Comment: The SSL support has been improved in Python 2.7.6 (AFAIR). EDIT: 2.7.9

Comment: My guess is that it is actually not Python 2.7.5 vs. 2.7.10 but the underlying OpenSSL version and configured ciphers. Please compare `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`. If you have an old and broken server which cannot deal with modern protocol versions and ciphers you might see this effect, i.e. that the server closes this connection as in this case. If the server is public you might add the URL to your question so that one could have a closer look.